# How to apply css to top level element only

Tags: css, css-selectors

In my HTML I have some footer elements within separate section, and then one global footer element for the page. I want to make only the global page footer to appear on the bottom of the viewport.

If I do this, it will affect all the footers:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;    
}
```

If I do this, it works as expected, but the `body` syntax looks akward:

```
body > footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;    
}
```

Is there a better way to specify top-level footer only?

Comment: Add a class to to your footer and apply your css to that particular class.

Comment: True, I guess I had a blind spot there :)

Comment: +1 for a class but whats wrong with `body > footer`?

Comment: @insertusernamehere I just never really seen that syntax anywhere, which was clue to me I may be doing something wrong

Comment: @SebastianK nothing is wrong with it, it selects "footer" that is a child of "body"

Comment: @DavidNguyen is right. Use it just like that. It's simple and highly readable.

Comment: Thanks guys that clarifies it for me. @reinder can you make your comment an answer? Number of upvotes speaks volumes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a class to to your footer and apply your css to that particular class.
As others pointed out there's nothing wrong with `body > footer` though.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the global footer would be the easiest fix or you can do:

```
body > footer:last-child
```

Comment: Yes, class would work. last-child would not work in my case, as section footers are last-childs of their section elements, so they are affected as well.

Comment: This will only work if the `footer` is really the last child within the `body` and if it's not the last child within the other elements where a `footer` appears. So this could still not work properly for the OP.

Comment: For the edit: Assuming there's only one `footer`within `body` and it comes last `body > footer` is the same as `body > footer:last-child` only shorter.